# Hardware wiring problem with keypad scan

Tags: keypad

I am trying to write  keypad (4*4) scan VHDL code for my [DE10-lite board](https://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&No=1021). In order to avoid floating signal for the input, I need pull up resistors.

[image]

There is an example I found from [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNOVg9vwFRM)

However, the keypad only has 8 pins. How can I connect Vcc with pull up resistors to it?

[image]

Comment: So the FPGA has no built-in pull-ups or pull-downs?

Comment: `the keypad only has 8 pins` ... why do you say `only`? ... the schematic diagram shows 7 pins ... your keypad has more pins than the schematic

Comment: @jsotola I use 4*4 keypad

Comment: the schematic diagram shows pullup resistors on all of the MCU input and output pins ... you connect the resistors the same way on your keypad

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your question is to re-draw it with the pull-up resistors at the other ends of the rows and columns.  It's electrically the same, but now the resistors can be connected to the pins.

Comment: Can you provide me a simple diagram as an example?

Answer (score 1):

If you have 4x4 keypad as shown in figure, this is how it looks internally
[image]

connect the pins 1-r1, 2-r2, 3-r3, 4-r4, 5-c1, 6-c2, 7-c3, 8-c4, there is no need of pull-ups.
but if you want, you can connect four 10k resistors from r1,r2,r2,r4 to Vcc.

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't work. The following from this link is working
https://learn.parallax.com/tutorials/language/propeller-c/propeller-c-simple-devices/read-4x4-matrix-keypad

Comment: @kile, It depends on how you write the scanning algorithm

Comment: How do you avoid floating signal of GPIO without resistors?

Comment: @kile, simply by connecting some pull ups or pull down resisitors, also i can use internal pull ups if present.